# Mod Rewrite direct .php access

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i want that direct .php requests get a notfound error.

The role looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^update/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ update.php?version=$1&action=$2 [QSA,L]
```

A correct request should be

```
http://localhost/update/0.95/info
```

But why does:

```
http://localhost/update.php/0.95/info
```

still work? Why does the role match?

thanks

Comment: I don't see how either of them would match, since the rule requires the URL to start with `update`, and the posted URLs start with `/test`. Are there any other rewrite rules in your configuration?

Comment: Sorry mad bad. Copy and paste mistake. Fixed it now.

Comment: To @Michael's defense he could've used the `RewriteBase /test/` directive :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rewrite rule does *not* match `http://localhost/update.php/0.95/info`. The query parameters version and action will not be set. The URL is still valid though so it will work and point to **update.php**.

Here's a SERVER extract from `/update.php/0.95/info`:

```
[QUERY_STRING] => 
[REQUEST_URI] => /update.php/0.95/info
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /update.php
[PATH_INFO] => /0.95/info
```

Comment: Yeah, how does it have to look like if i want that it wonr redirect it, cause of the .php? I hope you know what i mean. ty

Comment: I think I do. No redirect is made on the URL `http://localhost/update.php/0.95/info`, the webserver simply interprets the request to be a request for the **/update.php** file.

Comment: Thats a bit weird ^^. If i access
   http://localhost/update
i get a not found. Anything is wrong there. I should get a notfounf for the .php access aswell cause of the fact that the rule does not mach, like in the exaample above. I dont get it

Comment: @Michael Not at all, `localhost/update` does *not* point to an existing file and also the rewrite rule pattern does *not* match the URL - therefore a 404 not found. `localhost/update.php` works because the **update.php** file exists in the matched location.

Comment: Thats the thing. If i access localhost/update.php the ".php" gets removed and i get a not found. And thats the point i dont understand.

Comment: Okay. In a other browser that wont happen. Weird, must be the cache. So is there a way to create a rule for .php access and redirect them to notexists.php so that they get a notfound? ty

Comment: @Michael Yes, delete the file or do a redirect

Comment: When i delete the file then the correct request get a not found too ^^ And thats my question. How can i do a redirect if anyone tried to access a .php directly?

Comment: @Michael Hehe indeed. I see your point, it's a common request when doing `.htaccess` rewrites. The short answer is that you can't unless you do some fancy checks on the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable. The healthiest way is to change your URLs that point to *update.php* to simply *update* and then rewrite **update** to **update.php**